# how to detect when react-player fails to play due to youtube age/privacy restrictions

Tags: javascript, react-player

(*This might be a bug in the library, so also filed as a github issue [here](https://github.com/cookpete/react-player/issues/1241)*.)

I would like to detect when [react-player](https://github.com/cookpete/react-player) fails to play a youtube video due to privacy settings or age restrictions.  It seems that sometimes a play failure will result in `onError` getting called with error value 150 (corresponding to these sorts of restrictions) but it is not consistent.  (See below.)

Is there a recommended way to detect this failure condition?

The following steps show why the `onError` callback is insufficient for these purposes:

1. Go to the [react player demo](https://cookpete.com/react-player/) and enter url of a video that is age-restricted ([example](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Zqh47NQtRPU)) or private ([example](https://youtube.com/watch?v=qhIN5E35dZc)) into the `custom URL` text input, then click `load`.  *Content heads-up: both examples contain footage from the U.S. Capitol on January 6, 2021; neither load in the player at the time of writing this question.)*
2. Check the browser's javascript console.  Observe from the console log that `onReady`, `onDuration` and `onProgress` have fired, but `onError` is not present.
3. Now get the URL of a public video ([example](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2HFSaxIsJCE)), enter it into the `custom URL` field and click `load`.   Observe the player successfully plays the video.
4. Finally, re-enter the URL of the video in step 2 and press `load` once more.  This time, in the javascript console the message `onError 150` appears.

The goal is to get `onError` to fire in step 2 (or some equivalently reliable method of failure detection).

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the GitHub Issue is the place to discuss this.

Comment: @tadman rephrased to clarify that this might be a bug (thus the GitHub issue) or there might simply be a better way to accomplish the goal.

Comment: This involves a lot of highly domain-specific knowledge to even begin to diagnose, plus it will likely involve a non-trivial amount of time to resolve.

Comment: @tadman yes, definitely domain-specific